# Url rewrite, htaccess and PHP how to do it

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with this url and I want to know how to rewrite that into htaccess. I'm pretty new into this stuff so I'm curious on how to do this, for example this url:
WEBSITE/?page=online

and rewrite it to, for example:
WEBSITE/page/online

or this url:
WEBSITE/?page=account&hide=x

to, for example:
WEBSITE/page/account/hide/x

I use this PHP script to include the pages inside one HTML document:

```
    <?php

    if (empty($_GET)) 
    {
        include 'pages/index.php';
    } else {
        if (!file_exists('pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php' ))
        {
            header("Location: /");
        } else {
            include 'pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match SITE/page/account/hide/x, etc
RewriteRule ^/?page/([^\.*]+)/([^\.*]+)/([^\.*]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA]

# Match /SITE/page/online etc.
RewriteRule ^/?page/([^\.*]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: works perfectly ;) only one question how to make it that if i for example use the old one like ?page=x then make it automatic rewrite to the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) control.php [L]
```

This says take every request coming to your server and sends it into the control.php file. Then in control.php we process all the gets to directories. You'll probably want some fallbacks, e.g. no `GET` request; should it go to the root, 404, 403?

control.php

```
<?php
$parts = '';
foreach($_GET as $key => $directories) {
    $parts .= $key . '/' . $directories . '/';
}
header('Location: ' . '/' . $parts);
?>
```

Comment: How many redirects does it give you? It should only send one, only sending one on my tests. http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150222_4A_1EC/1/details/